# Counting parts of a Mitzvah as a Mitzvah (Rambam's 12th principle)

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah, rambam

Rambam in Sefer Hamitzvos lays [his own] principles of what counts as a Mitzvah and what's not. The 12th principle says that:

> שאין ראוי למנות חלקי המלאכה מהמלאכות שבא הצווי בעשייתם כל חלק וחלק בפני עצמו:

For example, although in the Torah, making the Menorah or that Altar are totally separate commandments, Rambam states that those are details of one Mitzvah of building a Temple. Similarly, all the actions of the High Priest on Yom Kippur fall under one Mitzvah of the practice of Y"K.

While many (esp Ramba"N object), Rambam doesn't seem to be consistent, for example (Hil. Avodah Zarah):

> 14 שלא לאהוב המסית.
>   15 שלא לעזוב שנאתו.
>   16 שלא להצילו.
>   17 שלא ללמד עליו זכות.
>   18 שלא ימנע מללמד עליו חובה.

It seems that all 5 could be easily gathered under דיו מסית. Similar patterns could be found in other books also.

Why is that?